# who is qualified to lead the Taraweeh prayer?

Tags: source-identification, authenticity, reference-request, quran-recitation

I attend a Mosque in an area where there are 2/3 brothers that have appointed themselves as Imams.
The one person has not memorized the Quran front to back and vise versa. Both self claimed Imams have not gone through any training as required to become an Imam.

In the holiest month did not bring an authentic Imam to lead the Taraweeh prayer instead he choose to do this himself.

My question is his actions correct or has he wronged the people who follow him in Taraweeh prayer?

I believe from researching and what the scholars have said is incorrect therefore the Taraweeh prayers are invalid.

I choose to follow online virtually authentic Imans reciting the Taraweeh prayers in the ISBCC to prevent from losing the blessings of this holy month Alhamdulillah because I could not find anyone to clarify my question in my community without offending anyone. I did not want to wrong myself or someone else in the blessed holy month. Ma shAllah

Comment: I don't know where you've done your research but following an imam online is certainly wrong and praying congregation this way is invalid. And the views on whom should lead a prayer differ from madhhab to madhhab, some hold the opinion that memorizing more of the qur'an is the first criterion others say fiqh knowledge in particular of the prayer is. And I'd assume this is answered somewhere on the site.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to think the Tarawih prayers are invalid... Knowing all the Quran is not a condition for being an Imam nor does it require some formal training.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as required training to be an Imam. Any adult, sane, male, unimpaired, muslim who knows recitation and how to perform salah is qualified to lead Taraweeh or any other prayer; and any salah offered under him is valid. After establishing that the preferable choice is someone who is the most pious, knowledgeable etc. from the available people - but again this is not a requirement for validity.

Refer to: [Islamic Jurisprudence According To The Four Sunni Schools](https://archive.org/details/IslamicJurisprudenceAccordingToTheFourSunniSchoolsAlFiqhalaAlMadhahibAlArbaah/page/n569/mode/2up?view=theater)